# could not get interface listener instanced in class

Tags: android, kotlin, interface

listener is unresolved 
i couldn't get why?
tried differently but no proper solution

> can anybody please tell me where is the problem why listener is red colored?

```
interface MessageListener(messageText: String) {

}
class SmsReceiver(listener: MessageListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        lateinit var number:TextView

        if(extras != null){
            val sms = extras.get("pdus") as Array<Any>

            for(i in sms.indices) {
                val format = extras.getString("format")

                val smsMessage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray, format)
                } else {
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray)
                }
                val phoneNumber = smsMessage.originatingAddress
                val messageText = smsMessage.messageBody.toString()

               // Toast.makeText(context, "From: $phoneNumber Message: $messageText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              // var a= Toast.makeText(context, "From: $phoneNumber Message: $messageText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              //  number.text="$phoneNumber"
                listener=this.listener
               listener.onMessageReceived(phoneNumber, messageText)
            }

            }

        }

    companion object {
        class onMessageReceived(public val phoneNumber: String?, private val messageText: String) : listener.onMessageReceived("$phoneNumber $messageText")
    }

}
```

Comment: On which line you got red line.

Answer (score 2):

First of all. Interface does not have constructor with Parameters. Add a method to the Interface like below:

```
interface MessageListener {
   fun onMessageReceived(messageText: String)
}
```

then in your class just add `"val" keyword` to the listener instead of `"listener=this.listener"`:

```
class SmsReceiver(val listener: MessageListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        lateinit var number: TextView

        if (extras != null) {
            val sms = extras.get("pdus") as Array<Any>

            for (i in sms.indices) {
                val format = extras.getString("format")

                val smsMessage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray, format)
                else
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray)

                val phoneNumber = smsMessage.originatingAddress
                val messageText = smsMessage.messageBody.toString()

                listener.onMessageReceived("$phoneNumber $messageText")
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

change :

```
interface MessageListener(messageText: String) {

}
```

to

```
interface MessageListener {

}
```

interfaces don't have constructors, the syntax you're using is for a constructor

Answer (score 0):

1. Interfaces can't have constructors. They just can't store any state:

   > Interfaces in Kotlin are very similar to Java 8. They can contain declarations of abstract methods, as well as method implementations.
   >   **What makes them different from abstract classes is that interfaces cannot store state.** They can have properties but these need to be
   >   abstract or to provide accessor implementations.

   An `abstract` class is probably what you should use in this case.
2. Your code in the `companion object` just doesn't make sense. After `:` goes the extended type, not an instance or method invocation.

This should work:

```
abstract class MessageListener(protected val messageText: String) {

}
class SmsReceiver(listener: MessageListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    // onReceive

   class OnMessageReceived(val phoneNumber: String?, messageText: String) : MessageListener("$phoneNumber $messageText")
}
```

However I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Change interface like this

Try this.

```
interface MessageListener {
  void onMessageReceived(messageText: String)
}
class SmsReceiver(listener: MessageListener) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val extras = intent.extras
        lateinit var number:TextView

        if(extras != null){
            val sms = extras.get("pdus") as Array<Any>

            for(i in sms.indices) {
                val format = extras.getString("format")

                val smsMessage = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray, format)
                } else {
                    SmsMessage.createFromPdu(sms[i] as ByteArray)
                }
                val phoneNumber = smsMessage.originatingAddress
                val messageText = smsMessage.messageBody.toString()

               // Toast.makeText(context, "From: $phoneNumber Message: $messageText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              // var a= Toast.makeText(context, "From: $phoneNumber Message: $messageText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
              //  number.text="$phoneNumber"

               listener.onMessageReceived("$phoneNumber $messageText")
            }

            }

        }

}
```